# Extract only certain rows using value_coutns

Tags: python, pandas

I have simple code that reads a CSV file and gives me a list of `value_counts` but I want to extract only certain rows from the `value_counts` results. Any suggestions how to do this?

*value_count results look like:*

```
domain_a.com            79
domain_b.de             51
domain_c.de             44
domain_d.com            43
domain_e.com            38
```

What I would like to be able to do is search through the results and return only those rows that match a certain domain name:

*desired results:*

```
domain_a.com            79
domain_c.de             44
domain_e.com            38
```

*Code so far:*

```
import pandas as pd

# read csv into the data dataframe
allData = r'/downloads/data/latest/export-2016-09-30-2039-55502fd6.csv'
tickets_df = pd.read_csv((allData),parse_dates=['Created at'],index_col='Created at')
tickets_df.fillna(0,inplace=True)

# Use 2016 data ony
tickets_2016_df = (tickets_df.loc['2016-01-01':'2016-10-20'])

org_counts = tickets_2016_df['Requester domain'].value_counts()
print (org_counts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert your series to DataFrame and then use [.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental) method:

```
In [120]: org_counts
Out[120]:
domain_a.com    79
domain_b.de     51
domain_c.de     44
domain_d.com    43
domain_e.com    38
Name: val, dtype: int64

In [121]: org_counts.to_frame('count').query("index in ['domain_a.com','domain_c.de','domain_e.com']")
Out[121]:
              count
domain_a.com     79
domain_c.de      44
domain_e.com     38
```

or using [Index.isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) method and [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
In [122]: domains = ['domain_a.com','domain_c.de','domain_e.com']

In [123]: org_counts[org_counts.index.isin(domains)]
Out[123]:
domain_a.com    79
domain_c.de     44
domain_e.com    38
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you!